# ._doc in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this js code

```js
app.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = UserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email}).exec()
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Not find user'
        })
        const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user._doc.passwordHash)
        if (!isValidPassword) return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Incorrect password'
        })
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'error'
        })
    }
})
```

And I have this Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    telegramUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatarUrl: String
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

In this line

```
const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user._doc.passwordHash)
```

I have error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'passwordHash'). Why am I getting an error? He writes to me that ._doc undefined but why? Help me please

Comment: You can access the property with `user.passwordHash`

Answer (score 0):

**use these two methods in your schema**

```
  const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
  // Create Hash Salt Password ..
  userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("passwordHash")) return next();
     this.passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(this.passwordHash, 12);
    next();
  });
  // Compare Password ...
   userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passwordHash) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(passwordHash, this.passwordHash);
  };
```

**And in your auth code**

```
app.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email}).exec()
    if (user) {
       res.status(400).json(
         { message: 'User already register'})
        }
       else{
         const newuser = New User({
           name: req.body.name,
           // also write other schema fields
           }
          const res = await newuser.save();
          console.log(res)
    
catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({
        message: 'error'
    })
}
```

})

***I hope this should resolve your problem***